# Something weird when typing in sudo hardinfo (Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module) and more

Tags: gnome-terminal

typed it in got this message, What is this?

```
$ sudo hardinfo
[sudo] password for yokoono147: 
Gtk-Message: 13:30:16.274: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Warning: truncated a line (probably flags list) longer than 896 bytes while reading /proc/cpuinfo.
Warning: truncated a line (probably flags list) longer than 896 bytes while reading /proc/cpuinfo.
Warning: truncated a line (probably flags list) longer than 896 bytes while reading /proc/cpuinfo.
Warning: truncated a line (probably flags list) longer than 896 bytes while reading /proc/cpuinfo.
Warning: truncated a line (probably flags list) longer than 896 bytes while reading /proc/cpuinfo.
Warning: truncated a line (probably flags list) longer than 896 bytes while reading /proc/cpuinfo.
Warning: truncated a line (probably flags list) longer than 896 bytes while reading /proc/cpuinfo.
Warning: truncated a line (probably flags list) longer than 896 bytes while reading /proc/cpuinfo.
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? In which terminal do you launch `hardinfo`? What is the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep flags`

Comment: I run Lubuntu and I need no sudo for hardinfo. It works well with the command `hardinfo`. You might have problems with hardinfo's graphics when running via sudo. -- I need sudo for lshw, I run `sudo lshw | less` in order to read the output in the viewer less.

Comment: @sudodus - not sure ur point.

Comment: @N0rbert - there's more than one terminal?

Comment: @JustinF, I meant that you should try to run `hardinfo` without `sudo`. If still no luck, maybe try with another tool, for example lshw: `sudo lshw | less`

Comment: @sudodus ya i figured that out at some point i thot i wrote back but apparenly not... anyway na that doesnt change anything and yea sorry bout not writing back but i dont think this site is very good, so , but it links to lenovo forums thats why im on it now. i dont get along w the ppl here, they close inquires for no real reason N ya, so i dont think ima be on here ill read the book. i told the people in charge of site but they dont care. i dont think i belong here. but ya sorry bout that (not writing back) thing . see ya.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truncated Line ? What is This?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353074/truncated-line-what-is-this)